# Drive REST API insert error, Error shows request is too long

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am getting error as Request is too large 400 OK while executing following Code,

```
 File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(filename);
    body.setDescription("");
    body.setMimeType(info.getContentType());
    body.setFileSize(size);
    body.setMd5Checksum(chk);
    body.set("content", myFile);

    if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
        body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId
                .trim().toString())));
    }
    ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(info.getContentType(),
            myFile);
    File upfile = service.files().insert(body, content).execute();
```

I am getting error on insert. And I am updating just 4 MB file to Drive.

Please give me solution for this ot any alter way to do this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable) it is specific for larger files :)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a resumable upload configuring the MediaHttpUploader of the Java Library

```
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
```

In this way the chunked uploaded is internally managed by the MediaHttpUploader

As you can see in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload#Resumable_Media_Upload), you can also set a custom `MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener` for monitoring the upload